# Download Firebase JSON Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Since I was unable to access my Gmail account after using a VPN, is it possible to download real-time Firebase JSON data? I know that Firebase can be deleted using Curl, but what about downloading it? I already have the token and URL for this.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Aside from that, it's hard to help without more information on what the actual problem is. How are your Gmail account or the usage of a VPN relevant to what you're asking? Did you try following the documentation on [accessing Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) either through the SDK for your target platform or through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)? Since you mention CURL, the documentation on [reading data with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) might be what you're looking for.